# Almost Sure Convergence of Sums of Independent Random Variables with the Same Distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

Let $\{X_n, Y_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a sequence of independent random variables, where for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $X_n$ and $Y_n$ have identical distributions. Prove that $X_n+Y_n \rightarrow 0$ almost surely if and only if $X_n \rightarrow 0$ almost surely and $Y_n \rightarrow 0$ almost surely.

I know how to prove the sufficiency, but I encountered some difficulties when proving the necessity. How can the almost sure convergence of the sum of random variables imply the almost sure convergence of individual random variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $X_n$ does not converge almost surely to $0$. This means there exists $\varepsilon>0$ and a measurable set $A$ such that $\mathbb P(A)>0$ and $\vert X_n\vert>\varepsilon$ on $A$ for infinitely many $n\in\mathbb N$. Up to considering $(-X_n,-Y_n)$ instead of $(X_n,Y_n)$, we can consider that $X_n>\varepsilon$ for $n\in I\subset\mathbb N$ where $I$ is infinite.

Then $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb P(Y_n>\varepsilon)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb P(X_n>\varepsilon)\ge\sum_{n\in I}\mathbb P(A)=+\infty$, so by Borel-Cantelli's lemma we get that $X_n>\varepsilon$ and $Y_n>\varepsilon$ almost surely for infinitely many $n$. We deduce that $X_n+Y_n$ cannot converge almost surely to 0, which proves the claim

Comment: I don't follow. That is already the case